# CC sender of a joruney email using a Dynamic Sender Profile (SFMC)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, cc

I set up a registration journey for new clients in SFMC. If the client doesn't register after we attempt to register the client from the organizations inbox a few times, I escalate and send an email using a dynamic sender profile that will send the email from the clients Account Manager or CSM.

I would like that escalation email to also CC the AM/CSM so that they can seamlessly follow up if the client still does not take action.

I tried putting a dummy address in the CC field and using a combination of hidden AMP and SSJS to update that dummy address to send the CC as the same sender as the DSP but that failed. I also tried referencing the sender various ways in the CC field directly.

Has anyone had any luck solving this problem?